# Convert SQL query with subquery to Sequelize query

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, subquery

I'm new to [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) and I want to convert the following `SQL query`:

```
select distinct user_id
from accounts_users
where user_id not in (
    select user_id
    from accounts_users
    where account_id = 2)
```

To a Sequelize query but I could not find a way to make the subquery right.

My try that does not work:

```
const existingUserIdsWithAccountUser = await AccountUserModel.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        user_id: {
          [Sequelize.Op.and]: {
            [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: Sequelize.literal(`SELECT user_id FROM 'Accounts_Users' WHERE account_id = ${account_id}`),
            [Sequelize.Op.in]: existingUsersIds
          }
        }
      },
      attributes: [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'user_id']
    }).map(user => user.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is equivalent to:

```
select distinct user_id
from accounts_users
where account_id <> 2
```

Let me know if I am missing anything.